# Periodic List in Python

Tags: python, list

I’m trying to create a circular list in Python. I.e., a list where `list[x]` is equal to `list[x - len(list)]` if `x` > `len(list)`.

Here is the code below:

```
class Circ(list):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        while (idx > len(self)):
            idx -= len(self)
        return super(Circ, self).__getitem__(idx)
```

However, I still get an error from the following code:

```
c = Circ([1,2,3])
c[3]
>> IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error. Python list indices start at *zero*, so valid indices are 0, 1 and 2. Since `3` is equal to `len(self)` however, you never reduce it.

Test if `idx` is greater than **or equal to** the length:

```
while idx >= len(self):
    idx -= len(self)
```

or simply use the `%` modulus operator:

```
return super(Circ, self).__getitem__(idx % len(self))
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Circ(list):
...     def __getitem__(self, idx):
...         return super(Circ, self).__getitem__(idx % len(self))
...
>>> c = Circ([1, 2, 3])
>>> c[3]
1
```

Comment: You’re right. Thanks. One problem though, now when I type `c[3]` I get `0 [line] 1` instead of just `0`.

Comment: @Y2H: There is no `0` in your input list. I'm not sure what interpreter console you are using, but `0 [line]` is not something the standard interpreter produces. See the demo in my answer.

Comment: Wait never mind, forgot my logging. OK thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that list indices are 0-based; hence, you want `while (idx >= len(self)):`.

Good test case!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your condition:

```
while (idx > len(self)):
    idx -= len(self)
```

You should replace it with:

```
while (idx >= len(self)):
    idx -= len(self)
```

although this is far from efficient. A more efficient way is to use modulo (`%`):

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return super(Circ, self).__getitem__(idx%len(self))
```

Modulo calculates a (positive) remainder after division (although if the divider is negative, the modulo is negative as well). For example:

```
>>> 2%4
2
>>> 3%4
3
>>> 4%4
0
>>> 5%4
1
>>> -5%4
3
```